# Error in setting MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, my.cnf

Operation failed:

```
Couldn't find section [mysqld] in the config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

It is with this error, what is it and how do I fix?

Comment: Happens to me also, could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I followed the link : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50030

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password       = your_password
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-locking
key_buffer_size = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 4
sort_buffer_size = 64K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 128K

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (using the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking
server-id       = 1

# Uncomment the following if you want to log updates
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
#binlog_format=mixed

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = /usr/local/mysql/data/
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /usr/local/mysql/data/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 8M
sort_buffer_size = 8M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Comment: As I had done as @ashishdhiman2007 had answered; Although Mysql workbench started but after restart mysql failed to start. So I deleted all extra sections from my.cnf except mysqldump and mysql (I left mymysqldump because i could set a big max_allowed_packed); that enabled mysql to start

Answer (score 1):

It means MySQL Workbench is looking for a [mysqld] section in your my.cnf file. It's standard to have one, so I suggest adding one. My test shows Workbench will add this for you, so I'm not sure why it's not for you, but ultimately the solution is to add it.